# What's wrong with my JS code for a command prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

This was working earlier, and then stopped. No idea why. It should function like this: enter a command into the textbox that is matched with an if statement, and execute the command. The form keeps refreshing after you press enter, so I don't think the "event.preventDefault();" at the end of my JS code is working.

## **HTML**

```
<form id="command-form" autocomplete="off">
    <img src="img/tint.png" alt="tint-img" id="tint-img" class="CMP">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" class="CMP" id="command-box">
    <img id="x-icon" src="img/x-icon.png" alt="x-icon" class="goto-command-console bottom-left-navigation-item" onclick="toggleCMP();">
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;" onclick="checkCommand();">
</form>
```

## **JavaScript**

```
function checkCommand() {
    var commandInput = document.getElementById("command-box");
    var form = document.getElementById("command-form");

    if ( commandInput.value === "help" ) {
        window.open("html/commandhelp.html");
    }
    if ( commandInput.value === "windows" ) {
        changeStyle('css/windows-xp.css');
    }
    if ( commandInput.value === "explicit pass:3XPL1C1T" ) {
        changeStyle('css/explicit.css');
        playMusic('other/audio/moaning.mp3');
    }

    form.reset();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

## **Edits**

A nice gentleman in the comments solved the problem, go check out his answer below. However, my method works too. In an earlier function, I did this:

```
function playMusic(url-to-mp3) {
    new Audio(url-to-mp3).play();
}
```

I wasn't even thinking about the dashes in the function object. Both methods work great, and thank you for your help. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Just change the submit input to a non-submit button if you don't want it to submit the form.

Comment: Your "submit" input is not visible; are you trying to use it to handle hitting the "Enter" key from the text input?

Comment: You also never pass in `event` or are closing any of your `input` tags

Comment: I think it might work as you expect if you get rid of the "submit" input and instead bind your handler to the `<form>` "submit" event. That way, calling `preventDefault()` will do what you expect.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console preventing `preventDefault` getting called,..  I would move the `event.preventDefault()` as the first line anyway..

Comment: @tymeJV  HTML5 doesn't use closing tags for `input` & `img`, your maybe thinking XML.

Comment: @Keith - Self-closing tags*

Comment: @tymeJV In HTML5, input tags **must not** be closed.  In XHTML, it **must** use a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works:

```js
function checkCommand(event) {
 event.preventDefault();

    var commandInput = document.getElementById("command-box");
    var form = document.getElementById("command-form");

    if ( commandInput.value === "help" ) {
        window.open("html/commandhelp.html");
    }
    if ( commandInput.value === "windows" ) {
        changeStyle('css/windows-xp.css');
    }
    if ( commandInput.value === "explicit pass:3XPL1C1T" ) {
        changeStyle('css/explicit.css');
        playMusic('other/audio/moaning.mp3');
    }

    form.reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="command-form" onsubmit="return checkCommand(event)" autocomplete="off">
    <img src="img/tint.png" alt="tint-img" id="tint-img" class="CMP">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" class="CMP" id="command-box">
    <img id="x-icon" src="img/x-icon.png" alt="x-icon" class="goto-command-console bottom-left-navigation-item" onclick="toggleCMP();">
    <button type="submit">Send me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah, updated it a bit. And added onsubmit event to be able handle it when Enter is pressed

Comment: I looked over where I put it in, and I put it on the wrong input lol. Accepted answer, thank you for your time.

Comment: Np, always check console :)

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="submit" style="display: none;" onclick="checkCommand();">` will submit the form on enter as its type is `submit` even you set to `display: none;`.

Changing its type to a button will solve your problem but you have to click the button to make it work or you have to handle the enter key (return key ) event to make call to the `checkCommand(event)`

```
<input type="button" onclick="checkCommand();">
```

The answer by @max is also a good one as it handles the event, but you have to understand a lot how that function is getting called with the event.

Comment: I was an idiot and didn't even think to check the JS console for errors. Turns out, my method works. In an earlier function, I did "function playMusic(url-to-music) {" not even thinking about the dashes in the function object name. Thanks for helping!